# Fitting a harmonic function into a time series in R

Tags: r, cycle, trigonometry

[image]

I got the following time series of residuals from another regression.
One index is a day. You can directly observe the year cycle.

Aim is to fit a harmonic function through it to expalain further part of the underlying time series.

I really appreciate your ideas about which function to use for estimating the right parameters! From acf we learn that there is also a week cycle. However, this issue i will adress later with sarima.

Comment: Do you mean something like y=a0+a1*sin(a2+2*pi*t/a3) for the monthly cycle, where a0 is mean (possibly zero), a1 is amplitude and a3 could be, e.g., 30 if t is in days?

Comment: I just edited my post a bit to make things clearer. Looking forward for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the sort of thing a fourier transform is designed for.

Try

```
fftobj = fft(x)
plot(Mod(fftobj)[1:floor(length(x)/2)])
```

The peaks in this plot corresponds to frequencies with high coefficients in the fit. Arg(fftobj) will give you the phases.

Answer (score 0):

Well i tried it, but it provides a forecast that looks like a exponential distribution. I solved the problem meanwhile in another way. I added a factor component for each month and  draw a regression. In the next step I smoothed the results from this regression and got a intra-year pattern that is more accurate than a harmonic function. E.g. during the June and July (around 185) there is generally a low level but also a high amount of peaks.